# Inserir imagem no fundo do site

Tags: css, html5, imagem

Olá! Sou novo em programação, e no momento estou estudando DESIGN E INTERFACE DA WEB. Gostaria de saber como insiro uma imagem como plano de fundo no site, para que o "corpo" do site (textos, links...) fique sobreposto sobre ela. Tipo como uma "marca d´água"... E ainda, quais tags ou comandos que posso usar para que a imagem fique ESTÁTICA ou COM ROLAGEM junto com a página.

Answer (score 0):

Basta vc fazer assim no css:

```
body{
  background-image: url('../img/fundo.jpg');/*Aqui você coloca o link da sua imagem*/
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backgrpund-position: center;
}
```

Desse jeito a imagem fica no fundo de todo o site, ou seja fica fixa e com o tamanho total da tela e sem repetição